# Upload and save image to server without refresh using Ajax and ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, file-upload

I have a VB ASP.net page that allow user to upload, crop and save the image and this hapens in a dialog so **I don't want to refresh** the page. So, I'm trying to use Ajax and not sure if it's possible.

Is there a way to let this work using my code? and if not is there a simple solution?

**Note:** I tested all these ASP codes and worked fine without Ajax

## The regular upload is like:

```
Private Sub btnUpoadToCrop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpoadToCrop.Click

    Dim objUpload As New Upload
    objUpload.MaxLength = 4000000

    '''' Upload Image File
    If objUpload.FileFieldLength(flImg) <> 0 Then

        Dim flImg As HttpPostedFile = Request.Files(0)
        Dim oFolder As String = "\media\temp-uploads\"
        Dim strName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(flImg.FileName).Replace(" " & "%20", "_").ToString
        Dim oFile As String = oFolder + strName

        '''' Save Original Photo
        flImg.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(oFile))


    End If

End Sub
```

## TRY AJAX

And because I couldn't access the flImg Image filed so tried to send variables from Ajax which didn't work with me and the console returning 500 (Internal Server Error)

## VB.NET

```
   Public Shared Function UploadSource(ByVal src As String, ByVal strName As String, ByVal ext As String) As String

    '''' Upload Image File

    Dim filesCollection As HttpFileCollection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files
    Dim fileName = filesCollection(0)
    Dim Name As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName.FileName).Replace(" " & "%20", "_").ToString

    Dim oFolder As String = "\media\temp-uploads\"
    Dim oFile As String = oFolder + Name

    '''' Save Original Photo

    fileName.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(oFile))

End Function
```

## jQUERY

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Ajax Upload
        var _src, _path, _name, _ext;
        $("#<%= flImg.ClientID%>").change(function () {
            //console.dir(this.files[0]);
            var val = $(this).val();    
            if (val != "") {
                _src = val;
                _name = _src.substr(0, _src.lastIndexOf('.'));
                _ext = _src.split('.').pop();
                _ext = _ext.toLowerCase();
                alert(_ext);
            }
            else {
                _src = "";
            }
        }).trigger('change');
        $(document).on("click", "#UploadSource", function () {
            if (_src != "") {
                alert(_name);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '/ImgCropper.aspx/UploadSource',
                    // *** I have set values for variables for test
                    data: "{'src':'" + "xyz.jpg" + "','name':'" + "xyz"+ "','ext':'" + "jpg" + "'}",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {

                   },
                   error: function () {
                       alert("some problem in saving data");
                   }
               });
            }


        });
     });
```

Then tried without sending variables in Ajax data with this function and with no hope still:

```
Public Shared Function UploadSource() As String


    '''' Upload Image File

    Dim filesCollection As HttpFileCollection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files
    Dim fileName = filesCollection(0)
    Dim Name As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName.FileName).Replace(" " & "%20", "_").ToString


    Dim oFolder As String = "\media\temp-uploads\"
    Dim oFile As String = oFolder + Name

    '''' Save Original Photo
    fileName.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(oFile))


End Function
```

Comment: Internal Server Error 500 could mean you might have to increase the upload limit in you web.config file, try uploading a really small image to see if this works. also in your server code you can add a on error handler to get a more detailed error.

Comment: I'm testing locally and uploading 50 K images .. also I have removed lines line by line and found the error happens before save when just trying to access requested file. do you mean my code is fine?

Answer (score 0):

Please download ajax file uplod script by using below link.

http://www.phpletter.com/DOWNLOAD/

Then your code should be like below.

Html:

```
<input type="file" id="fileupload" name="upload"/>

<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="52px"  OnClientClick="UploadFile();" />
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function UploadFile() {
var fileName = $('#fileupload').val().replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, '');

if (fileName != "") {
                $.ajaxFileUpload({ url: 'AjaxFileUploader.ashx',
                    secureuri: false,
                    fileElementId: 'fileupload',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        if (typeof (data.error) != 'undefined') {
                            if (data.error != '') {
                                alert(data.error);
                            } else {
                                alert('Success')
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (data, status, e) {
                        alert(e);
                    }
                }
                )
            }
}

});
```

**AjaxFileUploader.ashx:**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="AjaxFileUploader" %>
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Text
Public Class AjaxFileUploader
    Implements IHttpHandler
    Implements System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext)


        If context.Request.Files.Count > 0 Then
            Dim path__1 As String = context.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads")
            If Not Directory.Exists(path__1) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path__1)
            End If

            Dim file = context.Request.Files(0)

            Dim fileName As String

            If HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() = "IE" Then
                Dim files As String() = file.FileName.Split(New Char() {"\"C})
                fileName = files(files.Length - 1)
            Else
                fileName = file.FileName
            End If
            Dim newFile As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(fileName)
            newFile = String.Format("{0}{1}", newFile, fInfo.Extension)
            Dim strFileName As String = newFilename
            fileName = Path.Combine(path__1, newFile)
            file.SaveAs(fileName)


            Dim msg As String = "{"
            msg += String.Format("error:'{0}'," & vbLf, String.Empty)
            msg += String.Format("msg:'{0}'" & vbLf, strFileName)
            msg += "}"


            context.Response.Write(msg)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: I thought it's a PHP file handler isn't it?

Comment: @hsobhy, No, this is vb.net file handler. I have updated handler code. Please follow the instructions as I said. If you have any doubts in this implementaion, please ask me again.

Answer (score 0):

You can write WebMethod as following(its in C#)

```
[WebMethod]
public string UploadFile()
        {
                var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["UploadedImage"];
                //Your logic to save httpPostedFile
            }
        }
```

And on the page you can send file using jQuery as following,

```
<html>
<div>
        Select File to Upload:
        <input id="fileUpload" type="file" />
        <input id="btnUploadFile" type="button" value="Upload File" /></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#btnUploadFile').on('click', function () {
    $('#<%=hdnFileName.ClientID %>').val('');
        if (typeof FormData == "undefined") {
            alert("Please Use Latest Version Of Google Chrome Or Mozilla Firefox To Upload Documents");
            return false;
        }
                    var data = new FormData();

                    var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files;

                    // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
                    if (files.length > 0) {
                        data.append("UploadedImage", files[0]);
                    }
    else{
    alert('Please Select File');
    return;
    }

                    var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost/WebSite/WebPage.aspx/UploadFiles",
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: data
                    });

                    ajaxRequest.done(function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        alert("done");
                    });

                    ajaxRequest.error(function (xhr, status) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                        console.log(status);
                        alert(status);
                    });
                });
</script>
</html>
```

Remember, it may not work on some versions of IE, otherwise it works in Chrome and Firefox smoothly.